# Does it matter if two hashCodes are equal, even if the two objects aren't from the same type?

Tags: java, unique, equals, hashcode

Let's say I have two types `A` and `B` that both have a unique `id` field, here is how I usually implement the equals() and hashCode() methods:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof ThisType && obj.hashCode() == hashCode();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] { id });
}
```

In that case, given that `A` and `B` both have a 1-arg constructor to set their respective `id` field,

```java
new A(1).equals(new A(1)) // prints true as expected,
new A(1).equals(new A(2)) // prints false as expected,
new A(1).equals(new B(1)) // prints false as expected.
```

But also,

```java
new A(1).hashCode() == new B(1).hashCode() // prints true.
```

I wonder if it matters if two hashCodes are equal, even if the two objects aren't from the same type? Could hashCode() be used somewhere else than in equals()? If yes, to what purpose?

---

I thought about implementing the two methods as follow:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj != null && obj.hashCode() == hashCode();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] { getClass(), id });
}
```

Adding the class to the hashCode generation would solve this *potential problem*. What do you think? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For objects of different classes the same `hashCode()` does not matter. The `hashCode()` only says that the objects are possibly the same. If e.g. `HashSet` encounters the same `hashCode()` it will test for equality with `equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple:

- `A.equals(B)` implies `B.hashcode() == A.hashcode()`
- `B.hashcode() != A.hashcode()` implies `!A.equals(B)`

There should be no other relations between the two. If you use `hashcode()` inside `equals()`, you should have a warning.

Comment: Mathematically `X => Y` is equivalent to `!Y => !X`.

Comment: In cases where two objects' hash codes have already been computed, it may be worthwhile for `equals` to *start* by comparing hash codes, and if they're unequal don't bother looking at anything else.  In some cases it won't be helpful (e.g. if a `HashMap` calls `equals` on two objects, their hash codes are already *known* to be equal) but in some other scenarios it may save a lot of time comparing objects which are nearly equal.

Answer (score 0):

Hashcode is definitely **not** used in `equals`; it is used by collections based on the data structure called a *hash table*. It is always OK from the correctness standpoint for two hashcodes to equal each other; this is called a *hash collision*, it is unavoidable in the general case, and the only consequence is weaker performance.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with two different objects (even of the same type) to have the equal hash code, but your second variant of `equals()` looks odd to me.  It will work only if you can guarantee that your objects will be compared only to the objects of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Could hashCode() be used somewhere else than in equals()?
```

This method is supported for the benefit of hashtables such as those provided by `java.util.Hashtable.` from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

Also

The general contract of hashCode is:

- Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
- If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
  It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables.
- It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that **producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables**.

Answer (score 0):

Not that, when A extends B, or B extends A, then your equals method is faulty, since:

```
a.equals(b) != b.equals(a)
```

if a and b happen to have the same hash code.